# Battery replacement - 3-pin connector with 2-wire battery

Tags: batteries, replacement

I need help using a 10 kΩ fixed resistor. I connected the red and black wire but I'm not sure what to do with the white wire. I know that this is for the thermistor. The battery will not charge if the white wire is not connected.

I know that I need to use a resistor but I dont know where exactly to connect it. If you can show a picture on how the wires should be connected, it would be very helpful. P
My battery is a 3.7 V Li-po battery by the way.

I found a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152053/replace-3-wires-tablet-battery-with-2-wires-one) and I believe what the person did to resolve the issue is what I need to do. However, I have no idea on how to add the resistor.

[image]

Comment: Ah! A battery with a red, black and white wires. That narrows it down a bit from the thousands and thousands of battery types and chemistries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what i missed. Already edited my question. Cheers!

Comment: A photo and a link to the datasheet for the battery would be even better. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: We need a link to the **manufacturer's datasheet** for both the original and the replacement battery. A photograph of a generic battery is not helpful.

Comment: Darn it. I can't find that information. ='(

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer to the timeless 2 wire 3 wire question for tablet/GPS etc.
Although not yet done by me as I had already done the direct connection of white to black but have kept old battery for later.
My suggestion is transfer/change the old BMS to the new battery.
If you try this please provide feedback for other users.